# What does "?" stand for?

Tags: number-sequence

As stated in the title, what does the "?" stand for? 
If you want me to clarify something or if you want additional information, let me know. But this should be sufficient.

-30 04 50 = 16

-10 16 40 = 15

23 57 73 = ?

HINT 1:

> It's meant to say 04 and not just 4.

HINT 2:

> Separate the 3 numbers to the left(of the equal sign) into two parts.

Comment: JMP, I wouldn't call this a number sequence though. It could be misleading. More of a number-puzzle

Comment: Let me know if you want hint 2

Comment: This was probably harder than I thought, so I'll give you hint 2.

Comment: Well, I could do 50-34-00=16 and 40-16-11=15 with just mixing numbers (same way for both columns)

Comment: Ok. You could do that, but that's not the right approach to this problem. Mixing the numbers up, I mean. They are fixed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second hint was helpful.

> The numbers are coordinates.

Once you see things that way, it is not hard to see the relationship between the left and right side of the equality sign.

> The number to the right is the area of the triangle given by the coordinates.

The answer:

> 10